# How to play audio and record on headset at the same time in windows

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

I have a computer which has seperate ports for mic and headphones. I want to record using my headset's built-in mic **and** play audio at the same time(on the same headset). Basically I'm recording gameplay and want to listen to game sounds on my headset and since I do not have a mic I want to record me speaking too on the same headset. So it should recieve game audio and send mic audio at the same time.

Comment: So you are basically trying to record from a mic plugged into headphone jack ?

Comment: Kind of. My smartphone has only one jack and is used for both. When I record a video in it, it records using my headset mic and plays audio too at the same time. But my laptop has 2 of them seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Your headphones only has **one** cable and **one** jack, but it also has an **in-built** microphone, but you can't use the in-built microphone because your PC **does not support the jack.** Take a look on the jack you will see that there are **4 pins.** From the **tip to the base of the jack.**

To fix this, you will need an adapter to convert the headphone/mic single jack into seperate headphone and mic jacks. An example is here on amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-MUYHSFMM-Headset-Splitter-Adapter/dp/B0058DOWH6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058DOWH6)

Comment: That makes two seperate mic and headphone into one. I kind of need the opposite :(.

Comment: @Programmingcoder Sorry, wrong link. I updated it.